# Projective transformation of a projective line is a homography

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry

Let $K$ be a field. Prove that projective transformation of a projective line determined by an affine line $K$ is the same as homography.

This means that I need to prove that it has the form: $x \rightarrow \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}, \ \ a,b,c,d \in K, ad-bc \neq 0$.

I don't know how to approach this .

Could you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of a projective transformation?

Comment: I think in this context it's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation